# Relational Database User trying to understand Non-Relational and how to implement CRUD

Tags: security, cloudant, nosql

I'm currently involved in a app project, and I'm incharge of setting up the backend.
What i'm use to using is a MYSQL database + php for cleaning and managing the data sent to and fro the front end, which I have much more experience in.  However, because of certain preferences of my bosses, on this project I've found myself looking at IBMs Bluemix and Cloudant software.  Cloudant is a NoSQL database(like CouchDB) and my experience regarding noSQL is severely lacking.  All I've mananged to do so far is to create a few JSON documents, and some basic views

What I need to figure out is how to perform the CRUD(create,read,update,delete) actions on a NoSQL database, or at least what it would look like.

In addition to this, I need to know if there are ways to implement security measures(implement security and anti-hacking functions) on a NoSQL database without an external source, or will I need to learn how to reroute the data through some sort of php function first, if i want it cleaned, before sending it to the Cloudant server where my database sits.

Let me know if my attempt to explain my problem is lacking in clarity. I'll try my best to state a different way, if need be.

Comment: If you are new to couchDB or Cloudant I recommend spending an hour or so on a Getting Started: https://cloudant.com/learning-center/ or http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is nothing equivalent to an ANSI to NoSQL databases. In other words, NoSQL databases are not as standardized as SQL databases. All standards are starting to appear. You can think of it as a technology still in the making.

What you have in general is an API with methods such as `put_record` or `delete_record`, or a REST interface that is logically equivalent. Also, in general you CRUD the whole record, not parts of the record.

Take a look at the reference: [Cloudant - Reading and Writing](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/crud/)

Having that said, in your case I would recommend abstracting away from the specific implementation of the NoSQL you want to use if you care about avoiding vendor lock-in. So I would suggest you to wrap CRUD functions using PHP functions that later can be replaced if you want to change the NoSQL database flavor.

This approach has the additional advantage to provide an abstraction for you to implement your own security. Some important NoSQL databases have no concept of multi-tenancy or just implemented that. Again, it is a technology in the making.

When your mindset is the relational one, you tend to think of the database as something that will help you guarantee data consistency as much as possible. But NoSQL databases are not like that. Think of them as a simple repository of documents (in a JSON or XML structure, for instance), without cross references.

Then the obvious question is perhaps: why would anyone want such a thing? One of the possible answers is because NoSQL databases may hold an aggregate of consolidated data. You can then retrieve aggregates to save time reprocessing or re-retrieving data unnecessarily.

As for security, most (if no all) NoSQL databases have some pretty good authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Just saw this response. Thanks for speedy reply.  Does this mean that a writing a query for a NoSQL can at most add/delete a Json Document entry?  Or just that it isn't possible to implement a function on the NoSQL DB that provides cleaning of the data before being saved as a document?
The suggestion to wrap the CRUD functions using PHP functions is essentially a suggestion to have the app point to a php file first, which processes the data then sends it to the NoSQL db? 
Also, can you provide a very basic example of how a query for add?ing a document to a NoSQL might look

Comment: In general (and regarding NoSQL databases you always need to add "in general") NoSQL databases are document- or aggregate-based. There is no definition of columns of any kind. A document is a key-value tuple which may have a sort of hierarchy. So in the end you need to update the whole document, not part of it, or the equivalent to updating a single column in SQL. I will update my answer.